# pytest fails to discover tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I try to make pytest discover the tests I've written, but keep getting an error message that I don't really understand.

Some more details:
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.16, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\johndoe\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\projecting\project
plugins: dash-2.3.1

I get the following error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py",
> line 268, in wrap_session
>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py",
> line 321, in _main
>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py",
> line 265, in __call__
>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)   File
> "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py",
> line 80, in _hookexec
>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)   File
> "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py",
> line 60, in _multicall
>     return outcome.get_result()   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py",
> line 60, in get_result
>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py",
> line 39, in _multicall
>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py",
> line 332, in pytest_collection
>     session.perform_collect()   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py",
> line 657, in perform_collect
>     self.items.extend(self.genitems(node))   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py",
> line 827, in genitems
>     yield from self.genitems(subnode)   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py",
> line 824, in genitems
>     rep = collect_one_node(node)   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py",
> line 537, in collect_one_node
>     rep: CollectReport = ihook.pytest_make_collect_report(collector=collector)   File
> "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py",
> line 265, in __call__
>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)   File
> "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py",
> line 80, in _hookexec
>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)   File
> "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py",
> line 55, in _multicall
>     gen.send(outcome)   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py",
> line 769, in pytest_make_collect_report
>     out, err = self.read_global_capture()   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py",
> line 691, in read_global_capture
>     return self._global_capturing.readouterr()   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py",
> line 596, in readouterr
>     out = self.out.snap() if self.out else ""   File "C:\Users\johndoe\Anaconda3\envs\paglm_env\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py",
> line 454, in snap
>     self.tmpfile.seek(0) ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
```

Comment: Python 3.7 reached EOL and pytest-7.1.2 is almost 2 years old. Try updating the versions.